# If given $S=\sum \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ find the value of the corresponding alternating series $A$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think the problem I'm having with this is that I don't know what $S$ and $A$ stand for here. This comes from a list of problems in a chapter on infinite series and sequences. However, there is a problem that comes before this that I was able to solve, here it is:

Determine if the series
$$A={1-{1\over{2^2}} + {1\over{3^2}} - {1\over{4^2}} + {1\over{5^2}} - {1\over{6^2}}+}...$$
converges or diverges.

I was able to solve the above since the absolute value of ${(-1)^{n+1}}\over n^2$ = $1\over n^2$, so it is convergent by the $p$-series.

What does the question mean when it says to find the value $A$? Does it mean to find a sequence? Like $1\over n^2$?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Also, I was not able to find anything in this chapter that uses a capital 's' and 'a' to denote anything.

Comment: which book are you using?

Comment: Does it really say $\displaystyle {1+{1\over{2^2}} + {1\over{3^2}}+ {1\over{4^2}} + {1\over{5^2}}+ {1\over{6^2}}+ … {{\pi^2\over 6}}}$? It should say $\displaystyle {1+{1\over{2^2}} + {1\over{3^2}}+ {1\over{4^2}} + {1\over{5^2}}+ {1\over{6^2}}+ … ={{\pi^2\over 6}}}$

Comment: the new sum is $$\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: @Ovi you're right, it does have an = sign, sorry.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner how did you go about getting that? Is this a partial sum question? The reason I ask is because my book uses small case letters to denote these things.

Comment: As per evaluation of the series, let$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\\A=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2}$$Can you evaluate$$S-A$$in terms of $S$?

Comment: @DevHeavy Unfortunately for us, Dr. SG likes to post lots of comments of this form. He almost never leaves a good explanation, and many suspect he just plugs the numbers into a calculator (e.g. WolframAlpha) and posts the results.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thank you. I do not think I can evaluate that. What kind of question would this be do you think? Here are the things I don't understand about what you wrote. Why is A an alternating series? And why are you subtracting A from S? How would I even try to do that?

Comment: Subtract them directly.$$S-A=\left(\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{4^2}+\dots\right)-\left(\frac1{1^2}-\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}-\frac1{4^2}+\dots\right)$$There are some very similar terms don't you think?

Comment: I *think* the book is say $S = \sum \frac 1{n^2} = \frac {\pi^2}6$ and that $A = \sum \frac (-1)^{n+1}\frac 1{n^2}$.  So the questions are 1) does A converge and 2) is so what does $A$ converge to.  ... At least, that is how I would interpret the question to be.  Of course if we have no idea what is meant by A there's not much we can do.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I see, so subtracting those I end up with $5\over 8$? How does that answer the question? Is that the value of A? Thank you again.

Comment: @DevHeavy Wait, $\frac58$? How'd you get that? Perhaps I shall go color code them...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I subtracted ${1\over 1^2}$ and ${1\over 1^2}$, so they canceled out. Now I cancel ${1\over 3^2}$ and ${1\over 3^2}$. Then I add up the remaining, correct?

Comment: Not sure where the $\frac 58$ is from but not half the terms of A are the same as half the terms of S and the other half are the negative of the other terms of  S.  So S- A = 2 times the sum the absolute value of the negative terms of A.  i.e $S = a_1 + a_2 + a_3....$ and $A = a_1 - a_2 + a_3 - a_4+....$ then $S - A = 2a_2 + 2a_4 + .......$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you've got the convergence part, so here's a hint for evaluating the alternating series:

\begin{align}\left(\color{green}{\frac1{1^2}}+\color{#4477aa}{\frac1{2^2}}+\color{green}{\frac1{3^2}}+\color{#4477aa}{\frac1{4^2}}+\dots\right)-\left(\color{green}{\frac1{1^2}}-\color{#4477aa}{\frac1{2^2}}+\color{green}{\frac1{3^2}}-\color{#4477aa}{\frac1{4^2}}+\dots\right)&=2\left(\color{#4477aa}{\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{4^2}+\frac1{6^2}+\dots}\right)\\&=\frac12\left(\frac1{1^2}+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\dots\right)\end{align}

Notice that all the green terms cancel and all the blue terms double, and the last step being

$$2\times\frac1{(2n)^2}=\frac12\times\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: I see. duh, now the A value is $1 \over {2n^2}$...

Comment: You could say that its the sum of $\frac1{2n^2}$ from $n=1$ to $\infty$, but as written, $A\ne\frac1{2n^2}$. This would suggest that the value of $A$ varies as $n$ varies.... $A$ is a constant...

Comment: Oh, so A is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1\over{2n^2}}$ Since it is a constant, and the sum of that is the constant.

Comment: Yup, looks right. From there you use known/given values.

Comment: You're the best. Thanks again, you really helped me understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

If $S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2}}$ Then $S-A=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2}}=\sum\limits_{n even} \frac{2}{n^{2}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{(2n)^{2}}=\frac{2}{4}S$ so $S-A=\frac{1}{2}S$ so $A=\frac{1}{2}S$

Comment: On the step with the even numbers, your numerator should be a $2$, since $1-(-1)^{n+1}=2$ for even $n$.